# Nuitka TypeError compiler error object of type 'generator' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, scons, nuitka

When I compile with Nuitka (`nuitka --standalone file.py`) I get the following type error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\inline_copy\bin\..\lib\scons-3.0.1\SCons\Taskmaster.py", line 241, in execute
    if not t.retrieve_from_cache():
  File "C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\inline_copy\bin\..\lib\scons-3.0.1\SCons\Node\FS.py", line 2925, in retrieve_from_cache
    return self.get_build_env().get_CacheDir().retrieve(self)
  File "C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\inline_copy\bin\..\lib\scons-3.0.1\SCons\Environment.py", line 1016, in get_CacheDir
    cd = SCons.CacheDir.CacheDir(path)
  File "C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\inline_copy\bin\..\lib\scons-3.0.1\SCons\CacheDir.py", line 163, in __init__
    if os.path.isdir(path) and len(f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.basename(f) != "config") != 0:
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

I've already reinstalled Nuitka and pip installed Scons successfully. But I keep getting this error when it compiles. I'm not sure what's going on and I can't find answers to my problem other places.

Comment: The scons source I've been able to find [seems to have a different line 163](https://scons.org/doc/3.0.1/HTML/scons-api/SCons.CacheDir-pysrc.html#CacheDir) that wouldn't have this problem, even though both claim to be version 3.0.1

Comment: Replacing it seems to have solved my issue... I do however think that you should create an answer instead of a comment so I can mark it :)

Comment: I don't think it's a particularly good solution to the problem. Your real concern should be why you have an old/defective version, and how you can update it successfully.  Hotfixing packages in site-packages means that your environment isn't really reproducible, which means that it would be very difficult for you to share your code.

Comment: I have the newest version of Nuitka which includes the newest version of Scons. I've uninstalled it and reinstalled it to no difference. I'm not sure what version to get though.

Comment: Did you replace len() with just []? An non empty list should also be true...

Comment: Can you bring this issue to the users mailing list. This may be a bug in SCons and discussing it there is a prerequisite to filing a bug.  Ideally with a small (as in a few lines) SConstruct which demonstrates the issue..